# swift indexPath.row==0 works weirdly for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsindexpath, uitableviewrowaction

I am trying to make a table wherein first cell has a differernt layout than the rest. I want to put the image as background for first cell i.e it shd look something like this:

[image]

and here is the code for my implementation

```
 func imageCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> MainTableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(imageCellIdentifier) as MainTableViewCell
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject

    let eTitle:NSString = object.valueForKey("title")!.description
    let deTitle  = eTitle.stringByDecodingHTMLEntities()
cell.artTitle.text = deTitle


    var full_url = object.valueForKey("thumbnailURL")!.description
    var url = NSURL(string: full_url)
    var image: UIImage?
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        image = UIImage(data: data)
        if((indexPath.row)==0)  {
        var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, cell.frame.width - 10, cell.frame.height - 10))
        imageView.image = image
       cell.backgroundView = UIView()
      cell.backgroundView?.addSubview(imageView)

        }
        else{
        cell.thumb.image = image
        }
    })

    return cell
}
```

bt the problem is.. when i scroll down and scroll up back again, the background image starts repeating and the thumbnails also get overlapped as shown:
[image]

If i scroll up and down again.. this is wht happens:
[image]

i might have done some silly mistake bt m not able to figure out what it is. pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In table views cells are reused* and **you should reset parts of the cell** that are not relevant the specific version of the cell style you are after. Something like:

```
 if((indexPath.row)==0)  {
      let frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 
                             cell.frame.width - 10, cell.frame.height - 10)
      var imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
      imageView.image = image
      cell.backgroundView = UIView()
      cell.backgroundView?.addSubview(imageView)

      // Reset 
      cell.thumb.image = nil
 } else{
      cell.thumb.image = image
      // Reset 
      cell.backgroundView = nil
 }
```

Even better and more idiomatic idea is to use separate `UITableViewCell` designs for these two cell types, each with different reuse identifiers. This way you don't need to care about resetting.

P.S. You should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` instead of older `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` as it guarantees that a cell is returned.

Comment: I had started with making 2 different cells bt as there is core data involved, i switched to the easier one.. bt will definitely work on both of your suggestions once the basic app gets ready. thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the cell is being reused by the tableView for efficiency purposes but it is never being reset.

You need to clear / remove the imageView from the background view if the cell is not at indexPath 0.